# Moving MS Graph API parameters in oData.Feed call from url to Query

Tags: powerbi, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I have a following call to MS Graph API in Power BI

```
OData.Feed("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls(fromDateTime="&DateTime.ToText(Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(),-1),"yyyy-MM-dd")&",toDateTime="&DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(),"yyyy-MM-dd")&")", [ Authorization = "Bearer " & access_token ], [ ExcludedFromCacheKey = {"Authorization"}, ODataVersion = 4, Implementation = "2.0" ])
```

Where I need to move fromDateTime and toDateTime parameters to Query, so something like

```
OData.Feed("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/getDirectRoutingCalls", 
              [ Authorization = "Bearer " & access_token ], 
              [ ExcludedFromCacheKey = {"Authorization"}, ODataVersion = 4, Implementation = "2.0", 
                 Query=["fromDateTime"=DateTime.ToText(Date.AddDays(DateTime.LocalNow(),-1),"yyyy-MM-dd"),
                        "toDateTime"= DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(),"yyyy-MM-dd")] 
                ])
```

Query is for Power BI hence the DateTime.ToText functions
Specific is that link doesnt have "?filter" but just parameters in brackets strait after link without any "?".
Any idea if its possible at all?
Thanks